# Naming style for SQL columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, primary-key, built-in

Primary keys in databases are commonly named "id", which is problematic when using tools like SQLAlchemy to compose your database layout in Python:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

Obviously, this overwrites the built-in function [`id`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping). Ok, it is only overwritten in that very small scope of attribute references, however, I might need `id` in there. The other problem is that syntax highlighting tools treat the name "id" as a function and highlight it accordingly, regardless of the context. This can prominently be seen in [SQL-Alchemy's tutorials](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping). The third one is, it simply feels dirty.

An naive approach to the problem would be to make syntax highlighting aware of the special contex. However, this cannot be a solution since it only disguises the original problem and thereby may cause further problems.

This leads me to the assumption that renaming may be a possible soution. If I renamed the primary key to something like `user_id`, there would certainly be situations in which I would have to type

```
current_user = User('Peter')
print(current_user.user_id)
```

And `current_user.user_id` looks and feels very redundant and cumbersome to me. This is because I know from the context that `current_user` is actually an instance of User. Genrally, it does not matter which table is queried and how to variable is name to which the result is assigned to. Hence, prepending "xxx_" to the class variables of `Xxx` is very obviously a remedy for a symptom that was caused by a whole other problem and is therefore not a good solution.

Other posibilities are pre- or appending an underscore to "id". However, prepending is also not an option since it would interfere with Python's convetion for [non-public API parts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). So, from my point of view the following is the best solution available:

```
class User(Base):
    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

However, I am new to databases and I don't know how such problems are solved in practice or whether this is considered a problem at all. So, my question is:

How would one name the primary key of tables in SQL-like databases declared using SQLAlchemy and Python3, such that the build-in `id` is not overwritten and there is minimal redundancy and obfuscation in the resulting code.

Comment: `.id` as an attribute name is fine. The fact that this is dealt with poorly with syntax highlighters is... unfortunate

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a great fit for SO as its very opinion based but I'll let others decide that. Anyway, I pretty much do your last solution but I name the database column `id` and just use the `id_` label in python-land. `id_ = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)` if I'm worried about namespace. I always hate when I do `User.user_id` as it feels very redundant typing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) says:

> `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts
>   with Python keyword, e.g.
>
> ```
> Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
> ```

So using `id_` is fine.

However, since `id` is not actually a keyword, only a built-in function, using `id` would be fine, too, as long as it doesn't cause problems with shadowing the `id` function.

Naming a function parameter or variable `class`, would be a syntax error on the other hand, that's why the convention exists.

Comment: SQLAlchemy itself does this a lot in it's own source, `and_`, `in_`, `not_` et al.

Comment: yeah but note, `id` is *not a keyword*. It is merely a name in the builtin namespace. It's fine to use it in a class namespace

Comment: I've often wondered why sqlalchemy uses the trailing underscore on the column methods, like `.filter(some.column.in_([...])`, as the namespace can't be an issue there. Perhaps just to be consistent with the expression functions?

Comment: @SuperShoot `in` is a keyword, so a method can't be named like it.

Comment: Oh there you go, I suppose I'd never tried it. That's obviously why then. Cheers.